# SELECT COUNT * SQL PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I have to search if a postal code is in my database, my table is called "test" there is only one table in my database with one column and one row, the column is named "codes", and there is an only row with the INT 63000, i have a form in my website where client enter a code, and it called a .php file which check if the value is missing or present in the database, i don't know PHP so it's hard for me... :( And my code don't work :(

SOLVED : THIS IS THE WORKING CODE :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php  

if($_POST['code-postal'] === '') { 
        $hasError = true;
} else {
        $variable = $_POST['code-postal'];
        $code = intval($variable);
}

    mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx')
or die("I cannot connect to the database because: " . mysql_error());   

mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxxx');  

$code = mysql_real_escape_string($code);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM test WHERE codes='$code'"; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

if($data['total_count'] == 1) {
    $verif = true;
}
else {
    $verif = false;
}
// on ferme la connexion à mysql 
mysql_close();  
?>
```

Comment: Your query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE codes='$code` is perfect. What is the error you facing ?

Comment: `$row` is a stray variable, that's why.

Comment: There is no error, a blank page, i try to make an echo but it doesn't appear... What i have to do :/ ?

Comment: What is a stray variable ?

Comment: It means it's there alone, not doing anything or defined to do any other work. Error reporting would have signaled undefined variable "row" same thing for `$verif`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh i missed it, i have to put $req ?

Comment: Add this `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);` on top of your `if` condition.

Comment: Fred it works ! Thank yout but it works for every variable, i tested with many possibilities and the verif is already true, it should not be true at each time :(

Comment: Ok, you need to add/reference a row variable to that. See the answer given below.

Comment: I answer after adding your line :/

Comment: Duh, my bad `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` you're using `mysql_` - The other one had `mysqli_`.

Comment: I have : 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE codes='$code'"; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if($row == $code){
     $verif = true;
}
else {
     $verif = false;
}

Comment: It's true with each test :/

Comment: After `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` add `$check_code = $row['codes'];`  then do `if($check_code == $code)` that ought to do it.

Comment: Seems to be true already every time :/, i have : $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE codes='$code'"; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$check_code = $row['codes'];
if($check_code == $code){
     $verif = true;
}
else {
     $verif = false;
}

Comment: I would remove the `COUNT` because that is counting all your rows/columns in turn always returning TRUE because there is data in the rows, you're just not matching the one you want. You want to either do `SELECT *` or `SELECT codes`

Comment: with : $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE codes='$code'";  it's seems to bee already true every time :/

Comment: It works !!!!!!!!!! :)))))))))) I deleted : $code = mysql_real_escape_string($code); and it works ! Thank you very much !!! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. You know that Stack lets you put in your own answer.

Comment: There's no need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on a variable you've cast as an integer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM test WHERE codes='$code'"; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

if($data['total_count'] == 1) {
    $verif = true;
}
else {
    $verif = false;
}
```

Here is the working code.

`mysql_query` would return result set. You will need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function to retrieve data from that.

I guess you would have more rows in table in future, because as you mentioned in table that you have only one table with one column and one row, then there is no need of database, you can directly compare values.

Comment: Thank you ! But the variable seems to be false at each time even if i test with my row which is in the database :( what i have to do ? Is it possible the connection with the database is bad ? :/

Comment: It should show some error, if there is problem with your connection as you are already using `die` function. Try to see what query is actually being fired by using `echo $sql;` statement just after you initialize it.

Comment: This is the query the echo show : SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM test WHERE codes=''

Comment: So your `$code` value is not initializing properly. You have to look into that. Your query should work fine, once you assign proper value to `$code`

Comment: I just put my HTML code in the answer below, can you check if it's correct :/ ? Thank you for your time

Comment: Well good that it worked but you should escape your `$code` variable for security. Try putting the `$code = mysql_real_escape_string($code);` line after you establish mysql connection.

Comment: I don't know how to do that :/ it's easy ?

Comment: Thank you !!! It seems to work i put it before the  $sql = " line !! :))) Thank you very much !! :)